# How can I make a password with if and the text of a label?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, tkinter

I made a command so that when pressing a button, a text is added to a label, and what I want to achieve is that if you put the correct combination, and then press a button to confirm, then a window opens with some text that I will choose later.
The thing is, I don't know how to make a text from a lab work to make an if :(
How can I make the text inside "trad" the password?

```
def salir():
    if 

def a():
    trad.config(text=trad["text"]+"ar.")

def b():
    trad.config(text=trad["text"]+"ab.")
    
def i():
    trad.config(text=trad["text"]+"iz.")
    
def d():
    trad.config(text=trad["text"]+"de.")
    


ventana=tk.Tk()
ventana.title("Bosque")
ventana.geometry('900x800')
ventana.resizable(0,0)

frame = tk.Frame(ventana)
frame.pack()

canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, width=900, height=800)
canvas.pack()

leta = ""

trad = tk.Label(ventana,text=leta,wraplength=220,anchor="n")
trad.config(bg="#137420", fg="#E59866",font=("Verdana",10,"bold","italic"),width=25, height=9)
trad.place(x=660,y=160)

#caja = tk.Entry(ventana, width=37)
#caja.place(x=660,y=200)


boton = tk.Button(text="  ↑  ",font=("Verdana",17), command=a)
boton.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton.place(x=745,y=330)

boton1 = tk.Button(text="  ↓  ",font=("Verdana",17), command=b)
boton1.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton1.place(x=745,y=423)

boton2 = tk.Button(text="  Ir  ",font=("Verdana",16), command=salir)
boton2.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton2.place(x=746,y=379)

boton3 = tk.Button(text=" → " ,font=("Verdana",17), command=d)
boton3.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton3.place(x=812,y=376)

boton4 = tk.Button(text=" ← ",font=("Verdana",17), command=i)
boton4.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton4.place(x=686,y=376)
ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question.

Comment: How can I make the text inside "trad" the password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want? I did what I could understand.

```
from tkinter import messagebox as msg
def salir():
    global posx    #variables de alcance para todo el script no solo la función
    global posy
    global ima

    if trad["text"]!="ar.de.ab.iz.ar.iz.ab.de.":
        msg.showerror("Error","Incorrect Password")
        trad.config(text="")
    else:
        new_windw=tk.Toplevel()
```

Comment: Oh so that's how it was done, thank you very much: D

Comment: I think I was wrong about something, what I wanted to achieve was that the text is a defined text, and that if you write "ar.de.ab." then a window appears, but if not, another window appears saying to try again

Comment: Yes, then ```messagebox``` is doing that. @Leandro

Comment: Hey, I got another question, I tried to put a "Elif" but It doesnt work :( This: ||||| elif trad"text"]=="ar.ab.iz.": |||||

Comment: You forgot a ```[```

Comment: oh... gracias :)